# Travel to the UK with a reduced felony

Tags: visas, uk, legal, criminal-records

I was convicted on a marijuana possession charge in 2010. I received nine months in county jail and three years probation sentence. I completed without incident. I have never been in any other trouble. My conviction was reduced to a misdemeanor and dismissed.

- Do I need to apply for a visa?
- What are the chances of being denied?

I am planning on attending a wedding in 2019 in Wales.

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: I am a US citizen

Comment: Why would say to not apply?

Comment: @Deborah he means show up at the border without a visa.

Comment: @TheZealot Then you should put your reasoning into an answer to the question

Comment: I am surprised that someone would get 9 months in prison for a simple possession charge...

Comment: Consult a legal attorney, but if the case was *dismissed*, you shouldn't  have a conviction to report.  Unless only the higher class charges were dismissed in exchange for a plea to lower charges.  You need to understand you exact legal situation first before even thinking about Visas.

Comment: "I am surprised that someone would get 9 months in prison for a simple possession charge..." Perhaps the OP is a person of color, for whom such a sentence is not surprising.